# Debugging my code in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using JBoss with IntelliJ. I am running Jboss outside intellij. i.e running in Command Prompt. If that is the case, Can I debug my code in IntelliJ

Answer (score 14):

You can debug any running JVM, even remote on a different computer via JDWP. First you need to prepare JBoss (same thing applies to any JVM) to listen for debugger connections on a given TCP/IP port:

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y, transport=dt_socket,address=5005, suspend=n
```

This set of parameters has to be added to Java options, look for `JAVA_OPTS` variable in your JBoss startup scripts. Once this is done, JBoss will listen on 5005 port for debugger  connection. The very first line in JBoss console after starting it up should be:

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
```

Now you can attach your IntelliJ by choosing:

1. Run
2. Edit configurations
3. "+" (Add)
4. Remote
5. `localhost`/`5005` are fine

Comment: I added configuration in run.sh of Jboss and i did configurations in Intellij. When i run the code in IntelliJ it is showing "Unable to connect 1099" I started running Jboss in Command Prompt.

Comment: AFAIR 1099 is an RMI port in JBoss, choose a different one for a debugger. Also see my edit to the answer.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks for the step-by-step.